Uncaught Could not find Livewire component in DOM tree
Im using dragablejs to make a list of goals for an OGSM maker, and for that I take the information from dragable and use it in my livewire comonent to update every goal's listorder attribute. But I cant figure out this console error: Uncaught Could not find Livewire component in DOM tree
Note:
When I clear the cache, my code works ONCE, and then I get a blank screen with the error again:
Uncaught Could not find Livewire component in DOM tree
#[on('updateOrder')]
public function updateOrder($ids) {
    // dd($ids);
    $currentposition = 1;
    foreach($ids as $id) {
        $goalToEdit = Goal::find($id);
        $goalToEdit->listposition = $currentposition;
        $goalToEdit->save();
        $currentposition++;
    }
}

What I tried:
Single Initialization: Ensured that @livewireStyles and @livewireScripts are included only once.
Correct Component Rendering: Verified that the Livewire component is correctly initialized in the Blade file.
JavaScript Debugging: Checked that SortableJS is properly initialized and emitting events.

From what I can see from your example code given, your event names need to be in kebab-case. Also, are you using the key and wire:key properties? It looks like you have one component that renders all goals. Without your rendering code, I cannot say if this your updateOrder event handler is enough for Livewire to understand the change it needs to do in the DOM.
Can you post your whole component?
